# Dragging issue in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
 $().ready(function () {
   $(".MySplitter").splitter();
});

/*
 * jQuery.splitter.js - two-pane splitter window plugin
 *
 * version 1.51 (2009/01/09) 
 * 
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses: 
 *   https://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php 
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html 
 */

/**
 * The splitter() plugin implements a two-pane resizable splitter window.
 * The selected elements in the jQuery object are converted to a splitter;
 * each selected element should have two child elements, used for the panes
 * of the splitter. The plugin adds a third child element for the splitbar.
 * 
 * For more details see: http://methvin.com/splitter/
 *
 *
 * @example $('#MySplitter').splitter();
 * @desc Create a vertical splitter with default settings 
 *
 * @example $('#MySplitter').splitter({type: 'h', accessKey: 'M'});
 * @desc Create a horizontal splitter resizable via Alt+Shift+M
 *
 * @name splitter
 * @type jQuery
 * @param Object options Options for the splitter (not required)
 * @cat Plugins/Splitter
 * @return jQuery
 * @author Dave Methvin (dave.methvin@gmail.com)
 */
; (function ($) {

    $.fn.splitter = function (args) {
        args = args || {};

        return this.each(function () {
            var zombie;     // left-behind splitbar for outline resizes

            function startSplitMouse(evt) {
                if (opts.outline)
                    zombie = zombie || bar.clone(false).insertAfter(A);
                panes.css("-webkit-user-select", "none");   // Safari selects A/B text on a move
                bar.addClass(opts.activeClass);
                A._posSplit = A[0][opts.pxSplit] - evt[opts.eventPos];
                $(document)
                    .bind("mousemove", doSplitMouse)
                    .bind("mouseup", endSplitMouse);
            }
            function doSplitMouse(evt) {
                var newPos = A._posSplit + evt[opts.eventPos];
                if (opts.outline) {
                    newPos = Math.max(0, Math.min(newPos, splitter._DA - bar._DA));
                    bar.css(opts.origin, newPos);
                } else
                    resplit(newPos);
            }
            function endSplitMouse(evt) {
                bar.removeClass(opts.activeClass);
                var newPos = A._posSplit + evt[opts.eventPos];
                if (opts.outline) {
                    zombie.remove(); zombie = null;
                    resplit(newPos);
                }
                panes.css("-webkit-user-select", "text");   // let Safari select text again
                $(document)
                    .unbind("mousemove", doSplitMouse)
                    .unbind("mouseup", endSplitMouse);
            }
            function resplit(newPos) {
                // Constrain new splitbar position to fit pane size limits
                newPos = Math.max(A._min, splitter._DA - B._max,
                        Math.min(newPos, A._max, splitter._DA - bar._DA - B._min));
                // Resize/position the two panes
                bar._DA = bar[0][opts.pxSplit];     // bar size may change during dock
                bar.css(opts.origin, newPos).css(opts.fixed, splitter._DF);
                A.css(opts.origin, 0).css(opts.split, newPos).css(opts.fixed, splitter._DF);
                B.css(opts.origin, newPos + bar._DA)
                    .css(opts.split, splitter._DA - bar._DA - newPos).css(opts.fixed, splitter._DF);
                // IE fires resize for us; all others pay cash
                if (!$.browser.msie)
                    panes.trigger("resize");
            }
            function dimSum(jq, dims) {
                // Opera returns -1 for missing min/max width, turn into 0
                var sum = 0;
                for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
                    sum += Math.max(parseInt(jq.css(arguments[i])) || 0, 0);
                return sum;
            }

            // Determine settings based on incoming opts, element classes, and defaults
            var vh = (args.splitHorizontal ? 'h' : args.splitVertical ? 'v' : args.type) || 'v';
            var opts = $.extend({
                activeClass: 'active',  // class name for active splitter
                pxPerKey: 8,            // splitter px moved per keypress
                tabIndex: 0,            // tab order indicator
                accessKey: ''           // accessKey for splitbar
            }, {
                v: {                    // Vertical splitters:
                    keyLeft: 39, keyRight: 37, cursor: "e-resize",
                    splitbarClass: "vsplitbar", outlineClass: "voutline",
                    type: 'v', eventPos: "pageX", origin: "left",
                    split: "width", pxSplit: "offsetWidth", side1: "Left", side2: "Right",
                    fixed: "height", pxFixed: "offsetHeight", side3: "Top", side4: "Bottom"
                },
                h: {                    // Horizontal splitters:
                    keyTop: 40, keyBottom: 38, cursor: "n-resize",
                    splitbarClass: "hsplitbar", outlineClass: "houtline",
                    type: 'h', eventPos: "pageY", origin: "top",
                    split: "height", pxSplit: "offsetHeight", side1: "Top", side2: "Bottom",
                    fixed: "width", pxFixed: "offsetWidth", side3: "Left", side4: "Right"
                }
            }[vh], args);

            // Create jQuery object closures for splitter and both panes
            var splitter = $(this).css({ position: "relative" });
            var panes = $(">*", splitter[0]).css({
                position: "absolute",           // positioned inside splitter container
                "z-index": "1",                 // splitbar is positioned above
                "-moz-outline-style": "none"    // don't show dotted outline
            });
            var A = $(panes[0]);        // left  or top
            var B = $(panes[1]);        // right or bottom

            // Focuser element, provides keyboard support; title is shown by Opera accessKeys
            $.extend({
                  browser : {
                      opera : /opera/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())
                }
            }) 
            //$.browser.mozilla = /firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
            //$.browser.webkit = /webkit/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

            //$.browser.msie = /msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
            var focuser = $('<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>')
                .attr({ accessKey: opts.accessKey, tabIndex: opts.tabIndex, title: opts.splitbarClass })
                .bind($.browser.opera ? "click" : "focus", function () { this.focus(); bar.addClass(opts.activeClass) })
                .bind("keydown", function (e) {
                    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
                    var dir = key == opts["key" + opts.side1] ? 1 : key == opts["key" + opts.side2] ? -1 : 0;
                    if (dir)
                        resplit(A[0][opts.pxSplit] + dir * opts.pxPerKey, false);
                })
                .bind("blur", function () { bar.removeClass(opts.activeClass) });

            // Splitbar element, can be already in the doc or we create one
            var bar = $(panes[2] || '<div></div>')
                .insertAfter(A).css("z-index", "100").append(focuser)
                .attr({ "class": opts.splitbarClass, unselectable: "on" })
                .css({
                    position: "absolute", "user-select": "none", "-webkit-user-select": "none",
                    "-khtml-user-select": "none", "-moz-user-select": "none"
                })
                .bind("mousedown", startSplitMouse);
            // Use our cursor unless the style specifies a non-default cursor
            if (/^(auto|default|)$/.test(bar.css("cursor")))
                bar.css("cursor", opts.cursor);

            // Cache several dimensions for speed, rather than re-querying constantly
            bar._DA = bar[0][opts.pxSplit];
            splitter._PBF = $.boxModel ? dimSum(splitter, "border" + opts.side3 + "Width", "border" + opts.side4 + "Width") : 0;
            splitter._PBA = $.boxModel ? dimSum(splitter, "border" + opts.side1 + "Width", "border" + opts.side2 + "Width") : 0;
            A._pane = opts.side1;
            B._pane = opts.side2;
            $.each([A, B], function () {
                this._min = opts["min" + this._pane] || dimSum(this, "min-" + opts.split);
                this._max = opts["max" + this._pane] || dimSum(this, "max-" + opts.split) || 9999;
                this._init = opts["size" + this._pane] === true ?
                    parseInt($.curCSS(this[0], opts.split)) : opts["size" + this._pane];
            });

            // Determine initial position, get from cookie if specified
            var initPos = A._init;
            if (!isNaN(B._init))    // recalc initial B size as an offset from the top or left side
                initPos = splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA - B._init - bar._DA;
            if (opts.cookie) {
                if (!$.cookie)
                    alert('jQuery.splitter(): jQuery cookie plugin required');
                var ckpos = parseInt($.cookie(opts.cookie));
                if (!isNaN(ckpos))
                    initPos = ckpos;
                $(window).bind("unload", function () {
                    var state = String(bar.css(opts.origin));   // current location of splitbar
                    $.cookie(opts.cookie, state, {
                        expires: opts.cookieExpires || 365,
                        path: opts.cookiePath || document.location.pathname
                    });
                });
            }
            if (isNaN(initPos)) // King Solomon's algorithm
                initPos = Math.round((splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA - bar._DA) / 2);

            // Resize event propagation and splitter sizing
            if (opts.anchorToWindow) {
                // Account for margin or border on the splitter container and enforce min height
                splitter._hadjust = dimSum(splitter, "borderTopWidth", "borderBottomWidth", "marginBottom");
                splitter._hmin = Math.max(dimSum(splitter, "minHeight"), 20);
                $(window).bind("resize", function () {
                    var top = splitter.offset().top;
                    var wh = $(window).height();
                    splitter.css("height", Math.max(wh - top - splitter._hadjust, splitter._hmin) + "px");
                    if (!$.browser.msie) splitter.trigger("resize");
                }).trigger("resize");
            }
            else if (opts.resizeToWidth && !$.browser.msie)
                $(window).bind("resize", function () {
                    splitter.trigger("resize");
                });

            // Resize event handler; triggered immediately to set initial position
            splitter.bind("resize", function (e, size) {
                // Custom events bubble in jQuery 1.3; don't get into a Yo Dawg
                if (e.target != this) return;
                // Determine new width/height of splitter container
                splitter._DF = splitter[0][opts.pxFixed] - splitter._PBF;
                splitter._DA = splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA;
                // Bail if splitter isn't visible or content isn't there yet
                if (splitter._DF <= 0 || splitter._DA <= 0) return;
                // Re-divvy the adjustable dimension; maintain size of the preferred pane
                resplit(!isNaN(size) ? size : (!(opts.sizeRight || opts.sizeBottom) ? A[0][opts.pxSplit] :
                    splitter._DA - B[0][opts.pxSplit] - bar._DA));
            }).trigger("resize", [initPos]);
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Hey guys, I'm using this script for splitting divs when drag a boarder. Its working fine in browsers but not in mobile. can you help me with that. Its important to make it happen in mobiles also. I have attached my demo link below for more details. Please help Thanks.
http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/ux-uxi/

Comment: It may be of a benefit to look at the *touch* events from mobile browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events -- my best guess is that binding to *mouse* events is not capturing things like `touchstart`, `touchend`, and so on...

Comment: Might have something to do with the used events since dragging is done a bit different on touchscreens. Browsers are pretty smart to transform it themselves but it might cause problems with more advanced things like this. Have you tried adding corresponding mobile events if possible? Or what else did you try?

Comment: Actually i didn't try anything. I don't know more about javascript. I'm new to this things. Can you help with that?

Answer (score 0):

This plugin doesn't support touch events. So you can try first read about using [Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events).

When you will be comfortable with them you can notice that this plugin uses `mousedown` to start moving split panel process, `mousemove` to actually move panel and `mouseup` to stop moving process.

On mobile devices you can use `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` correspondingly to achieve a similar result.

Also you will need to determine positions of your touches. So while they can be accessed via `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` in desktop browsers - on on mobile devices you have to access of the same properties but of particular touch you use (`event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX` and `event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY`).

To achieve working example you can replace your **index.js** content with the next one:

```
 $().ready(function () {
   $(".MySplitter").splitter();
});

/*
 * jQuery.splitter.js - two-pane splitter window plugin
 *
 * version 1.51 (2009/01/09) 
 * 
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses: 
 *   https://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php 
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html 
 */

/**
 * The splitter() plugin implements a two-pane resizable splitter window.
 * The selected elements in the jQuery object are converted to a splitter;
 * each selected element should have two child elements, used for the panes
 * of the splitter. The plugin adds a third child element for the splitbar.
 * 
 * For more details see: http://methvin.com/splitter/
 *
 *
 * @example $('#MySplitter').splitter();
 * @desc Create a vertical splitter with default settings 
 *
 * @example $('#MySplitter').splitter({type: 'h', accessKey: 'M'});
 * @desc Create a horizontal splitter resizable via Alt+Shift+M
 *
 * @name splitter
 * @type jQuery
 * @param Object options Options for the splitter (not required)
 * @cat Plugins/Splitter
 * @return jQuery
 * @author Dave Methvin (dave.methvin@gmail.com)
 */
; (function ($) {

    $.fn.splitter = function (args) {
        args = args || {};

        return this.each(function () {
            var zombie;     // left-behind splitbar for outline resizes

            function getEventPosition(evt) {
                return evt.originalEvent.touches && evt.originalEvent.touches.length ? evt.originalEvent.touches[0][opts.eventPos] : evt[opts.eventPos];
            }

            function startSplitMouse(evt) {
                if (opts.outline)
                    zombie = zombie || bar.clone(false).insertAfter(A);
                panes.css("-webkit-user-select", "none");   // Safari selects A/B text on a move
                bar.addClass(opts.activeClass);
                A._posSplit = A[0][opts.pxSplit] - getEventPosition(evt);
                $(document)
                    .bind("mousemove touchmove", doSplitMouse)
                    .bind("mouseup touchend", endSplitMouse);
            }
            function doSplitMouse(evt) {
                var newPos = A._posSplit + getEventPosition(evt);
                if (opts.outline) {
                    newPos = Math.max(0, Math.min(newPos, splitter._DA - bar._DA));
                    bar.css(opts.origin, newPos);
                } else
                    resplit(newPos);
            }
            function endSplitMouse(evt) {
                bar.removeClass(opts.activeClass);
                var newPos = A._posSplit + getEventPosition(evt);
                if (opts.outline) {
                    zombie.remove(); zombie = null;
                    resplit(newPos);
                }
                panes.css("-webkit-user-select", "text");   // let Safari select text again
                $(document)
                    .unbind("mousemove touchmove", doSplitMouse)
                    .unbind("mouseup touchend", endSplitMouse);
            }
            function resplit(newPos) {
                // Constrain new splitbar position to fit pane size limits
                newPos = Math.max(A._min, splitter._DA - B._max,
                        Math.min(newPos, A._max, splitter._DA - bar._DA - B._min));
                // Resize/position the two panes
                bar._DA = bar[0][opts.pxSplit];     // bar size may change during dock
                bar.css(opts.origin, newPos).css(opts.fixed, splitter._DF);
                A.css(opts.origin, 0).css(opts.split, newPos).css(opts.fixed, splitter._DF);
                B.css(opts.origin, newPos + bar._DA)
                    .css(opts.split, splitter._DA - bar._DA - newPos).css(opts.fixed, splitter._DF);
                // IE fires resize for us; all others pay cash
                if (!$.browser.msie)
                    panes.trigger("resize");
            }
            function dimSum(jq, dims) {
                // Opera returns -1 for missing min/max width, turn into 0
                var sum = 0;
                for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
                    sum += Math.max(parseInt(jq.css(arguments[i])) || 0, 0);
                return sum;
            }

            // Determine settings based on incoming opts, element classes, and defaults
            var vh = (args.splitHorizontal ? 'h' : args.splitVertical ? 'v' : args.type) || 'v';
            var opts = $.extend({
                activeClass: 'active',  // class name for active splitter
                pxPerKey: 8,            // splitter px moved per keypress
                tabIndex: 0,            // tab order indicator
                accessKey: ''           // accessKey for splitbar
            }, {
                v: {                    // Vertical splitters:
                    keyLeft: 39, keyRight: 37, cursor: "e-resize",
                    splitbarClass: "vsplitbar", outlineClass: "voutline",
                    type: 'v', eventPos: "pageX", origin: "left",
                    split: "width", pxSplit: "offsetWidth", side1: "Left", side2: "Right",
                    fixed: "height", pxFixed: "offsetHeight", side3: "Top", side4: "Bottom"
                },
                h: {                    // Horizontal splitters:
                    keyTop: 40, keyBottom: 38, cursor: "n-resize",
                    splitbarClass: "hsplitbar", outlineClass: "houtline",
                    type: 'h', eventPos: "pageY", origin: "top",
                    split: "height", pxSplit: "offsetHeight", side1: "Top", side2: "Bottom",
                    fixed: "width", pxFixed: "offsetWidth", side3: "Left", side4: "Right"
                }
            }[vh], args);

            // Create jQuery object closures for splitter and both panes
            var splitter = $(this).css({ position: "relative" });
            var panes = $(">*", splitter[0]).css({
                position: "absolute",           // positioned inside splitter container
                "z-index": "1",                 // splitbar is positioned above
                "-moz-outline-style": "none"    // don't show dotted outline
            });
            var A = $(panes[0]);        // left  or top
            var B = $(panes[1]);        // right or bottom

            // Focuser element, provides keyboard support; title is shown by Opera accessKeys
            $.extend({
                  browser : {
                      opera : /opera/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())
                }
            }) 
            //$.browser.mozilla = /firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
            //$.browser.webkit = /webkit/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

            //$.browser.msie = /msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
            var focuser = $('<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>')
                .attr({ accessKey: opts.accessKey, tabIndex: opts.tabIndex, title: opts.splitbarClass })
                .bind($.browser.opera ? "click" : "focus", function () { this.focus(); bar.addClass(opts.activeClass) })
                .bind("keydown", function (e) {
                    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
                    var dir = key == opts["key" + opts.side1] ? 1 : key == opts["key" + opts.side2] ? -1 : 0;
                    if (dir)
                        resplit(A[0][opts.pxSplit] + dir * opts.pxPerKey, false);
                })
                .bind("blur", function () { bar.removeClass(opts.activeClass) });

            // Splitbar element, can be already in the doc or we create one
            var bar = $(panes[2] || '<div></div>')
                .insertAfter(A).css("z-index", "100").append(focuser)
                .attr({ "class": opts.splitbarClass, unselectable: "on" })
                .css({
                    position: "absolute", "user-select": "none", "-webkit-user-select": "none",
                    "-khtml-user-select": "none", "-moz-user-select": "none"
                })
                .bind("mousedown touchstart", startSplitMouse);
            // Use our cursor unless the style specifies a non-default cursor
            if (/^(auto|default|)$/.test(bar.css("cursor")))
                bar.css("cursor", opts.cursor);

            // Cache several dimensions for speed, rather than re-querying constantly
            bar._DA = bar[0][opts.pxSplit];
            splitter._PBF = $.boxModel ? dimSum(splitter, "border" + opts.side3 + "Width", "border" + opts.side4 + "Width") : 0;
            splitter._PBA = $.boxModel ? dimSum(splitter, "border" + opts.side1 + "Width", "border" + opts.side2 + "Width") : 0;
            A._pane = opts.side1;
            B._pane = opts.side2;
            $.each([A, B], function () {
                this._min = opts["min" + this._pane] || dimSum(this, "min-" + opts.split);
                this._max = opts["max" + this._pane] || dimSum(this, "max-" + opts.split) || 9999;
                this._init = opts["size" + this._pane] === true ?
                    parseInt($.curCSS(this[0], opts.split)) : opts["size" + this._pane];
            });

            // Determine initial position, get from cookie if specified
            var initPos = A._init;
            if (!isNaN(B._init))    // recalc initial B size as an offset from the top or left side
                initPos = splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA - B._init - bar._DA;
            if (opts.cookie) {
                if (!$.cookie)
                    alert('jQuery.splitter(): jQuery cookie plugin required');
                var ckpos = parseInt($.cookie(opts.cookie));
                if (!isNaN(ckpos))
                    initPos = ckpos;
                $(window).bind("unload", function () {
                    var state = String(bar.css(opts.origin));   // current location of splitbar
                    $.cookie(opts.cookie, state, {
                        expires: opts.cookieExpires || 365,
                        path: opts.cookiePath || document.location.pathname
                    });
                });
            }
            if (isNaN(initPos)) // King Solomon's algorithm
                initPos = Math.round((splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA - bar._DA) / 2);

            // Resize event propagation and splitter sizing
            if (opts.anchorToWindow) {
                // Account for margin or border on the splitter container and enforce min height
                splitter._hadjust = dimSum(splitter, "borderTopWidth", "borderBottomWidth", "marginBottom");
                splitter._hmin = Math.max(dimSum(splitter, "minHeight"), 20);
                $(window).bind("resize", function () {
                    var top = splitter.offset().top;
                    var wh = $(window).height();
                    splitter.css("height", Math.max(wh - top - splitter._hadjust, splitter._hmin) + "px");
                    if (!$.browser.msie) splitter.trigger("resize");
                }).trigger("resize");
            }
            else if (opts.resizeToWidth && !$.browser.msie)
                $(window).bind("resize", function () {
                    splitter.trigger("resize");
                });

            // Resize event handler; triggered immediately to set initial position
            splitter.bind("resize", function (e, size) {
                // Custom events bubble in jQuery 1.3; don't get into a Yo Dawg
                if (e.target != this) return;
                // Determine new width/height of splitter container
                splitter._DF = splitter[0][opts.pxFixed] - splitter._PBF;
                splitter._DA = splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA;
                // Bail if splitter isn't visible or content isn't there yet
                if (splitter._DF <= 0 || splitter._DA <= 0) return;
                // Re-divvy the adjustable dimension; maintain size of the preferred pane
                resplit(!isNaN(size) ? size : (!(opts.sizeRight || opts.sizeBottom) ? A[0][opts.pxSplit] :
                    splitter._DA - B[0][opts.pxSplit] - bar._DA));
            }).trigger("resize", [initPos]);
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Oh man....you are awesome. It's working fine now. Thanks a lot...:) My best wishes to fly high bro...:)

Comment: @Danish by the way if this answer had helped you - it's better to accept it.

Comment: I'm using that in my project that means I accepted it. Do I want to do anything else for that? Actually I didn't get that. Please clear my confusions. Thanks :)

Comment: @Danish please read more about how to ask questions and accept answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  By the way as soon as I see you haven't accepted any answer to your 14 questions.